# Solving a first order differential equation diffrent from resolver

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this differential equation:

$$y'-\frac{xy}{1-x^2}y={xy^2}$$

divide for $y^2$

$$\frac {y'}{y^2}-\frac{x}{1-x^2}={x}$$

$$\frac {y'}{y^2}=\frac{x}{1-x^2}+{x}$$

$$\int\frac {y'}{y^2}=\int\frac{x}{1-x^2}+\int{x}$$

$$\frac{-1}{y}=\frac{-ln (1-x^2)}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}+c$$

$${y}=\frac{-2}{ln (1-x^2)-x^2-2c}$$

If I use a solver the result is

$${y}=\frac{-2}{-ln ((1-x)(1+x))+x^2+c-1}$$

Why is different?

Comment: I haven't found it yet, but note that the solver's result is just the negative of your answer which probably means you've missed a sign somewhere. '2c' can just be replaced with 'c' as it's a constant of intergration.

Comment: @Shuri2060 Its between his last two lines. He drops the minus on the left side.

Comment: @B.Goddard Ah right - yes. After flipping the fraction on both sides, the LHS was multiplied by $-1$ while the RHS has both the numerator and denominator multiplied by $-1$ which causes a sign to go missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at these two steps:
$$-\frac{1}{y}=\frac{-\ln(1-x^2)}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}+C$$
$$y=\frac{-2}{\ln(1-x^2)+x^2+C}$$
Do you see the problem? You dropped your negative. It should be
$$y=\frac{2}{\ln(1-x^2)+x^2+C}$$

As for the other discrepancies:

- The $-1$ in the denominator of the solver's answer is irrelevant, because it is just part of the constant.
- Your constant $C$ has a coefficient of $2$ and the solver's doesn't, but again, it doesn't matter, since it's just a constant.
- Your logarithms look different, but that's fine because $1-x^2=(1+x)(1-x)$